# Extracting reports from big tables in chunks

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

The question might sound a bit general. Still.
We have a table with hundreds of millions of records.
To make the report, several other smaller tables are being joined with it.
Indexes are created for all appropriate columns.
The client wants to get a report for a year+, that might be up to 100mil rows.

In order to secure the process, say if the script dies, or if the connection to the DB drops, the report must be extracted in chunks, so the next process picks up the report where the previous died.

The problem is that the report can be sorted by varchar/int columns, which can contain client names, account numbers, various personal data in different formats etc etc, and i haven't sorted out how to get a reasonable amount of rows for each chunk (say ~50k) in these cases.

Using limit x,y will take way too long with this amount of data.
There are no archived tables, no partitioning, data is not aggregated to separate tables. Just a huge chunk of data in one table.

Is there an established (magic?) way to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: Can you post the query and the explain of the query? Also, if it is not too much too ask, the schema?

Comment: Have you tried using unbuffered queries or an ID offset with PDO?

Answer (score 1):

"Is there an established (magic?) way to deal with this kind of problem?" -- You are asking about several things that I have spent a lot of time perfecting.

"hundreds of millions of records ... report" and "the report can be sorted by various columns" -- With a Summary table(s), that can run a lot faster:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables .  And a summary table helps with the sorting.

"Indexes are created for all appropriate columns" -- Sorry for my cynicism, but I have found that that phrase means that you have a bunch of single-column `INDEXes`, but have not learned about the benefit of suitable 'composite' indexes.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1

"using LIMIT and OFFSET" -- Here's why it is very inefficient:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination .  I don't see `OFFSET` being needed to solve your problem.  'Remembering where you left off' may helping in chunking to *initially* construct the Summary Table(s).

"connection to the DB drops" -- The above tips should make it fast enough to avoid this issue.  If not, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SELECT`, and possibly other details.

"chunking" -- Here are tips on chunking, but I don't think that is the solution for the problem at hand:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

"hundreds of millions of records ... in one table" -- Not a problem.  My tips are aimed at that size.

"no partitioning" -- Good.  I won't have to spend time convincing you that partitioning is unlikely to help:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

You win the prize.  I don't think I have ever pointed at 6 of my blogs to answer one Question.

Comment: We don't have summary tables where we would aggregate data. We do need a data warehouse of some sort, but every time the question is brought up the answer is "soon". We do have composite indexes. When sorting by a varchar column, it won't be that easy to remember where we left off, it won't be an incremented id anymore, so chunks may greatly vary in size if we remember the last several characters and compare. 
Considering all this, we decided to alter the task at hand, sorting will be by id and we'll be using the id key for sorting only.
Thank you for the tips, good blog too!

Comment: @ChungaChanga - re chunk size varying...  One of those blogs talks about using `LIMIT 1000,1` to find a stopping place 1000 rows forward.  This keeps the chunk size constant without worrying about the distribution of the keys.  That works well for a single-column index, but gets messier for composite.  But I address that somewhat.